# How to select certain test in VSTS?

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops

**How to select certain test to run in VSTS?**

I have few unit tests and I run them via build in VSTS - actually I have to run all of them from assembly. What I'm looking for is a feature similar to Visual Studio's Test Explorer - I want to select certain tests and run them from VSTS (not all of them).

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Visual Studio Test" task you can put value in `Test filter criteria` field:

[image]

This field is additional criteria to filter tests from Test assemblies (for example: `Priority=1|Name=MyTestMethod`).

You could then use the criteria to specify the specific class you want to run tests from using:

```
FullyQualifiedName~NameSpace.Test
```